# How to get an entity plus its child entities via RIA Services

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco, wcf-ria-services

I'm kind of new to EF and RIA so I'm not sure if this is supposed to work or not.

I have a simple model shown here:

[image]

I added the [POCO templates for entity framework](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313) and everything is wired as it sohould I can get Lazy Loading, Changes Notifications and Relationship Fixup... (I really hope you're still reading)

The thing is that while on the server I can load a Component's SubComponents by simply calling `comp.SubComponents`. BUT, for some reason I don't have that feature on the client side... My `Component` class from the `RIAServices.web.g.cs` (generated code) does not have a list of `SubComponent`.

Is that how that's suppose to work? Should I have a this function on the RIA Service?

```
public IEnumerable<SubComponent> GetSubComponents(int componentId)
{
    return m_ctx.SubComponents
           .Where(x => x.Component.Id == componentId)
           .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my metadata I was missing the attributes `[Include]` and `[Association]` in my Componet's metadata SubComponent property. The class has to look like this:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Component.Metadata))]
public partial class Component
{
    internal sealed class Metadata
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("ComponentSubComponent","Id", "ComponentId")]
        public ICollection<SubComponent> SubComponents { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I hope it helps someone :)

**extra tip**: I was having problems adding the `[Include]` attribute cause I was not referencing the right assembly. Make sure you add a reference to `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll`

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that I was also missing `ComponentId` property on the SubComponent entity

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about RIA services, but I doubt lazy loading can work from the client side... I think you need to load the `SubComponents` eagerly when you load the `Components`, before you send them to the client:

```
public IEnumerable<Component> GetComponents()
{
    return m_ctx.Components.Include("SubComponents")
           .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but the thing is my side Component does NOT have a SubComponents property :( thus I can't access a Component's SubComponent... I do can load the SubComponents 'by hand' and get them from the context (client context)